# Rotate img in bootstrap panel

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got an image inside bootstrap panel, i want to add functionality when i can click on a rotate button and the image would rotate.
i got the following:

```
.rotate{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); // IE9 only
          transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

if i add class to my img it rotates that 90degs but it comes out of the panel, it stops to follow the width and height restrictions, just rotates in place.
Is there a way to do that? I mean to rotate the image, in a way that it will still be in panel's borders.

**EDIT:**
i got this: http://jsfiddle.net/jjbjn160/
its overflowing the left side of panel, i want it to fit in to the panel.

Comment: Probably you want to use transform3d();

Answer (score 0):

set the style of the panel to overflow: hidden.

```
.panel {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: It just cuts my image, i want it to fit the panel, not trim it in half

Comment: you can get the width and height via javascript and change the width and height of the panel each time you rotate it :)

Comment: I think you dont understand, i can't change that, the image is flowing away on the left, example: http://jsfiddle.net/jjbjn160/

Comment: that is too cheap for me :( i need this nice and clean